# undefined method `topic_post_comments_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im getting the error where it can't recognize the following path on one of my partials:

```
<%= form_for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %>
```

Can someone tell me a possible solution?

This is the call on the partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals:{topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @post.comments.build } %>
```

This is my comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  validates :body, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

and these are the routes outlined in my routes.rb file:

```
Bloccit::Application.routes.draw do
  get "comments/create"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update]
  resources :topics do
     resources :posts, except: [:index] do 
        resources :comments, only: [:create]
     end
  end

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

And these are the results when i run rake routes | grep comments:

```
comments_create GET    /comments/create(.:format)          comments#create
topic_post_comments POST   /topics/:topic_id/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format) comments#create
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe define method: `form_for [topic, post, comment], method: :post do`

Comment: should work according to what I can see.

Comment: what happens if you just use: `comment: Comment.new`
 ?

Comment: Have you restarted your Rails server since editing the routes.rb? When proper syntax fails, I start wondering if a simpler explanation is the cause.